# Need help in rigging!

Tags: rigging

I needed someone to help me or recommend a good site or course that would help me to learn how to rig manually like a professional.I google tutorials on rigging and all I get is videos about riggfy and blendrig and I'm sick of it,because these addons don't help really much.like in the picture,I want to know how to do such complex rigs manually.I want to know how these things work.if anyone can help please reply. Thanks[image]

Comment: you have a lot of tutorials on Youtube, just type "rig character blender" and you'll a lot of results, then follow many of those

Comment: I highly recommend The Complete Blender Creator Course, which covers rigging without using addons. It's often on sale for £10.99 and well worth the price (though probably not worth £195 the quoted full price) if you want to learn how to use Blender better.
https://www.udemy.com/blendertutorial/learn/v4/overview

Comment: Thanks guys,earlier on YouTube I would still get the riggify videos but now I still checked and found some help helpful tutorials

Comment: I understood the concept of fk and ik bones

Comment: But I have one problem left.what are these "DEF" for like what does the acronym stand for and what is its fiction in the rig

Comment: And also the same situation for bones named "CON"

Comment: DEF = Deforming (bones which influence the geometry), mch = mechanics bones, ctl = control bone touched by the animator, L_ = left, R_ =right, C_ = center

Comment: OK got the acromyn,but does setting up of this "DEF" and "CON" bones effect the mesh transformations.like do they improve you character rig?

Comment: I've followed a lot of tutorials about rigging and never heard about def and con, I guess everyone has his own way to name bones

Comment: Hey I can help with this here are some links I think would be helpful to you :3
[First Link ʕ•ᴥ•ʔ](https://youtu.be/f2pTkW-1JkE?list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6) [Second Link •́▾•̀ ](https://youtu.be/S-2v_CKmVE8?list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6)

Answer (score -1):

I was analyzing the rig setup that you find in riggify,they had the DEF bone naming system.thought It was something that had do with rig setup of the riggify pack only, but I download another model by another artist and had the same DEF bone naming system so I thought it was a thing[image]

Comment: The artist did the rig set up manually though and did not use riggify

Answer (score -1):

Humane Rigging tought me how to rig from scratch.

You can watch it online for free
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-0oBXJZwQE

Or buy the DVD in the Blender store
https://store.blender.org/product/humane-rigging/